# Autosetting Function Names based on Parameter Input in PHP

Tags: php

I am making an AJAX script right now.  I have an html file, a javascript file, and a PHP file.

The JavaScript file will have a function will pass the parameter request_name to a URL.   The PHP script that catches the request has a switch statement that calls a different function based on request_name value.  The functions names are the request_name values, i.e. if $_REQUEST['request_name'] is "test_function", then the switch statement calls test_function().

Since the parameter name value will be the same as the function name, is there any way to basically just have PHP call request_name_value if that parameter is set.  It seems easier than having a switch statement, espeically since there will be a lot of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$func = "mynamespace_".$_REQUEST["request_name"];
if (function_exists($func)) {
    $func();
} else {
    header("Location: /index.html");
    exit;
}
```